# Laravel deleting with whereIn, not working boot deleting in Model

Tags: laravel

when deleting through whereIn, the boot method deleting in the Model does not work, when I delete through foreach everything is ok, is there a solution?
Controller

```
      $objects = Tutorial::whereIn('id', $request->get('objects'))->delete();
```

Model (Tutorial)

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            $model->user_id = auth()->id();
        });

        static::deleting(function ($model){
            $model->clearMediaCollection('media');
        } );
    }
```

If deleting with Foreach boot deleting is work
Example:

```
 foreach($objects as $object){
  $object->delete();
  // boot in model work!
 }
```

Comment: `->whereIn()` returns a Builder instance, which has a `->delete()` method to perform SQL-level delete. It looks like this doesn't instantiate Models and perform the callbacks. Do `->get()` instead of `->delete()`, then `foreach ($objects as $object) { $object->delete(); }` as you've already suggested.

Comment: From docs: "When issuing a mass update or delete query via Eloquent, the saved, updated, deleting, and deleted model events will not be dispatched for the affected models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when performing mass updates or deletes."